# Multiple time pickers in same activity

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I am Making an app that requires three time pickers. Each Time picker is defined in my button on click listener.

```
// What Happens When Item Is Clicked//
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

        // What Happens When Select Time Button Is Clicked//
        case R.id.SelectTime:

            // Create Calender Instance//
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance
                    (this, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ,calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false, false);

            timePickerDialog.setVibrate(isVibrate());
            timePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TIMEPICKER_TAG);
        break;

        // What Happens When Select Time End Button Is Clicked//
        case R.id.SelectTimeEnd:
            // Create Calender Instance//
            final Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

            final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog2 = TimePickerDialog.newInstance
                    (this, calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ,calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false, false);

            timePickerDialog2.setVibrate(isVibrate());
            timePickerDialog2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TIMEPICKER_TAG2);
            break;
    }

}
```

This Then gets transferred down to here so the time can be read on a text view.

```
//Controls Time//
@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String timeSet = "";
    if (hourOfDay > 12) {
        hourOfDay -= 12;
        timeSet = "PM";
    } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
        hourOfDay += 12;
        timeSet = "AM";
    } else if (hourOfDay == 12)
        timeSet = "PM";
    else
        timeSet = "AM";

    String min = "";
    if (minute < 10)
        min = "0" + minute;
    else
        min = String.valueOf(minute);

    // Append in a StringBuilder
    String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hourOfDay).append(':')
            .append(min).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();
    sttime.setText(aTime);
  }
}
```

The problem is when I use the other time picker for the other button it only recognizes the same textview, how do I make multiple onTime Sets so I can have all three time pickers on the same activity?

Comment: are you using only one text view ?

Comment: I am using two sttime and endtime. The secound one isnt there because i cant figue out how to add it but no to different textviews

Comment: sorry i cant understand what you are trying say